# Print out multiple words with alternating uppercase and lowercase

Tags: ruby

I cannot run my code.

I want to write down 50 words, but the even words `[0,2,4,6,8,...]` are all uppercase and the odd words are lowercase.

What other ways of writing this code are there? Should I start a new array and have `index = []`?

```
words = []

50.times do
   puts "Please enter a word:" 
   words << gets.chomp
end

puts "These are your wonderful words. You are smart. Keep it up."

%w(words).each_with_index {|word, index|}
if index = word.even?
        puts word.upcase
if index = word.odd?
        puts word.downcase

end
```

Comment: Try to use `even?`/`odd?` on index. The `=` seems unnecessary. The `words` array doesn't need `%w(...)` since it's already an array of String values.

Comment: %w(words) makes an array with one element, the string "words" -- you probably don't want %w.

Comment: This isn't a Rails question, it's elementary Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `%w(words)`:

```
words # => ["a", "b"]
%w(words) # => ["words"]
```

`%w(...)` converts every space-delimited string of characters into a separate String element in an array:

```
%w(a 1) # => ["a", "1"]
```

You can't interpolate your `words` variable into an array that way. There is no reason to, as you'll already have an array of String elements in your `words` array since you've already said it's an an array using:

```
words = []
```

and

```
words << gets.chomp
```

This is not good code:

```
if index = word.even?
        puts word.upcase
if index = word.odd?
        puts word.downcase
```

You can't test for equality using `=`. Instead that is assigning. Ruby is not interpreted BASIC:

```
a = 1 # => 1
a == 2 # => false
```

You can't do `word.even?` or `word.odd?` because words aren't even or odd, only integers are.

```
1.even? # => false
1.odd? # => true
'foo'.even? # => 

# ~> -:3:in `<main>': undefined method `even?' for "foo":String (NoMethodError)
```

Also, you'd need to use closing `end` statements.

Corrected that would look like:

```
if index.even?
  puts word.upcase
end
if index.odd?
  puts word.downcase
end
```

But that can be written more succinctly and clearly:

```
folded_word = if index.even?
                word.upcase
              else
                word.downcase
              end

puts folded_word
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things here.

You are setting them equal using `=` in your `if` statements.  You need to use `==` to test for equality whereas one `=` sets equality.  You're also missing an `end` if you use two `if` statements so instead use an `if`/`else`:

```
word = ["letter","booyah","sorry"]

word.each_with_index do |value, index|
    if index % 2 == 0  #(this is a modulo, when no remainder it is even)
          puts value.upcase
    else 
          puts value.downcase

    end
end
```

The result is:

```
LETTER
booyah
SORRY
```

Also, your `chomp` method won't be defined unless you put something in the `word` array first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) ?

```
words.each_slice(2){|w| p w[0].downcase; p w[1].upcase}
```

It requires an even number of words though.